# onclick of button navidate to another lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am not able to open a lightning component using "e.force:navigateToComponent" 
this is the error when i click on the button:
[image] 
this is my 1st component:

```
<aura:component controller="RecruitmentClass" implements="force:appHostable" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="LoginName" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="LoginPwd" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute type="Interviewee__c" name="Candidate1"/>

<div class="slds-text-align_center slds-size_1-of-3" >
    <lightning:card title="" >
        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_large">Login</h2><br/>
        <ui:inputText label="Enter your name " value="{!v.LoginName}"/><br/>
        <ui:inputText label="Enter your password " value="{!v.LoginPwd}"/><br/>
        <lightning:button  label='Login' onclick="{!c.myAction}"/><br/>
    </lightning:card>
</div>
```

this is my js controller:

```
({
myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    var name=component.get('v.LoginName');
    var pwd=component.get('v.LoginPwd');

    var action=component.get("c.Login");
    action.setParams({
        n:name,
        p:pwd
    });
    action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        if(response.getState()==='SUCCESS'){
            var c=response.getReturnValue();
            component.set('v.Candidate1',c);

            //this is where im facing problems
            var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
            evt.setParams({
                componentDef : "c:RecruitmentApp2ParentComponent",
                componentAttributes: {    Candidate : c 
                                     }
            });
            alert('succesful'+evt+'candidate: '+c);
            evt.fire(); 
        }
        else {
            alert('error something happend');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
}
```

})

Comment: Problem seems to be in your apex class

Comment: I dont htink this is a duplicate, as the other post was related to the context in which the component was running, this seems to be more related to the apex controller failing somewhere

Comment: Based on the poster's comment as to where the error happens (inside the callback *from* the Apex controller), I don't think it is the Apex that's at fault, and it likely is a duplicate pending clarification from aishwarya.

Comment: the duplicated issue is suggesting that you run the component in a context which is not supported by the `force:navigateToComponent` event. @aishwarya - where do you run this component from (community or whatever...)?

Answer (score 0):

According to Your Error,
  You missed double quotes in action.setParms

```
 action.setParams({
     "n":name,
     "p":pwd
  });
```

***Suggestion:***

How the way you passed the arguments in client side, same way you need to receive it in server side

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void Login(string n,string p){

 }
```